# Cant display attached images in Notes on a SSRS Report (CRM Dynamics Online)

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2008, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-sales

I'm trying to display images on an SSRS Report. The images are stored in attachments within a notes section.
I tried with both MIME Type JPEG and PNG but nothing works.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Image field inserted in the report:**

[image]

**Image Properties :**

[image]

**Results after running the report:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the Report Object itself you need to calculate the picture by using CALCFIELDS. Otherwise it will always appear empty.

Comment: and if im not wrong, you need to call the Convert.ToBase64String function on the report end as well (RDLC)

Comment: hello, I tried to use "=System.convert.toBase64String(Field!Documentby.Value)" but it didn't work

Comment: Is the picture being calculated?